# UIButton title not displaying

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I just started developing in Swift.

I created an UIButton dynamically and added it to the View.
My issue is the view is not displaying the button.

**My Code:**

```
var button:UIButton = UIButton();
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 250, width: 100, height: 50);
button.setTitle("Midhun", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
self.view.addSubview(button);
```

Then I added image to the button and then it is showing:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "step_first.jpg"), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
```

I couldn't figure out what is happening. Please help

Comment: I had this exact problem earlier, that it's white by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually figured out the issue.

In Swift the title of `UIButton` is white.

I changed the background color of parent View, now it is showing.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: Thats some valuable information that its default white, thanks

Comment: At first when I copy/pasted your code I saw the button but then I realized the text was white, definitely good to know that these attributes need to be set properly. Probably won't effect most people who have very custom UIElements.

Comment: Alternatively, you can change the *text color* to black by using the setter `.setTitleColor`

Answer (score 18):

In case you subclass UIButton and override its `layoutSubviews()`, make sure you call `super.layoutSubviews()` inside

Answer (score 12):

For me the issue was that I wasn't using the setter methods.

I was doing `notificationsButton.titleLabel?.text = "x"` instead of `notificationsButton.setTitle("x", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Comment: Yet you need to change the text color notificationsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal) of the title or the background color of the button notificationsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

Comment: Swift 5 : myButton.setTitle("myButtonText", for: .normal)