# How to remove image and write text in a UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button that displays an image from my Assets, on click of a button I want to replace the image by text,

I am doing this,

```
workExpExpand.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
workExpExpand.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
```

the image disappears, but the text is blank.

What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is correct. So I suspect you are having the same issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019573/uibutton-title-not-displaying). For fixing it you need to set the title color of that button, by default the title color is white and that's why you are not seeing the text:

```
workExpExpand.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code is right. But you have specify the title color as default color is white due to which you are not able to see text.

---

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        btn.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        btn.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**For swift 5 to remove image from button and set title**

```
self.btnRecord.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
self.btnRecord.setTitle("REC", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
workExpExpand.setImage(UIImage(), forState: .Normal)
workExpExpand.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4 & 4.2

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourBtn:UIButton!

@IBAction func yourBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {
        yourBtn.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        yourBtn.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code when you button pressed as you get will sender of UIButton so you can change here:

`IBAction func AnswerButtonA(sender: UIButton){
     //sender is the button that was pressed
     sender.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
}`